# FILTRAR UM ARRAY COMPLETO COM FILTER JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, array, filter

Estou tentando filtrar um array completo com filter e não estou tendo sucesso. Confira meu código e se possível me ajude.

Preciso remover um array que está contido em outro. 
Exemplo:

```
let array01 = [{id:50}, {id:51}, {id:52}, {id53}];
let array02 = [{id:50}, {id:51}, {id:52}, {id:53}, {id:54}, {id:55}];
```

Preciso retornar:
`newArray = [54, 55]`, ou seja, preciso remover o `array01` completo.

O que estou fazendo:

```
let newArray = array02.filter(function(item){    
for(let i = 0; i < array01.lenght; i++){ 
     return item.id != array01[i].id;
}
})
```

Mas não funciona. Eu consigo remover apenas o primeiro item do `array01`.
Pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, Obrigado pela sua resposta. Nesse caso específico eu estou recebendo os dois arrays através de uma consulta no banco de dados e preciso mostrar os itens em uma FlatList. Onde o novo array, ou seja o que será mostrado precisa excluir o array01.

Answer (score -2):

Olá!
Pra começar, com as high order functions(HOF) como o próprio filter, você pode escrever a callback  como arrow function assim, pra ficar mais fácil a leitura:

```
array.filter((item) => )
```

Se vc quer retornar só o 54 e o 55 da maneira que mostrou, não precisa de nenhuma interação com esse primeiro array(array1). Basta fazer:

```
let newArray = [];
array2.forEach((item) => (item.id === 54 || item.id === 55) && newArray.push(item.id));
```

eu supus o que você queria fazer, já que não foi tão clara sua pergunta. Se eu tiver viajado bastante, pode reformular, por favor?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Existem [diferenças claras e importantes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) entre uma função "tradicional" e uma arrow function, então a escolha entre elas vai muito além da "facilidade de leitura" (que aliás, é bem subjetivo). Dito isso, ele não quer filtrar sempre 54 e 55, ele quer remover de array2 os elementos que estão em array1 (ou seja, ele não sabe a princípio que vai sobrar 54 e 55, pois pra isso ele teria que comparar os arrays antes)